# Error in syntax on Firebase database rules

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

```
{
    "rules": {
        "Users": {
            "$user_id": {
                // Grants write access to the owner of this user account
                // whose uid must exactly match the key ($user_id)
                ".write": "$user_id === auth.uid"
            }
        }
        "$businessName": {
            ".write": "root.child('Users').child(auth.uid).child($businessName).child('Permission    s').val() === 'MODERATOR'"
        }
    }
}
```

This is giving me an error:

> Error saving rules - Line 10: Expected ',' or '}'.

The error says I'm missing a bracket for some reason. Did I miss a comma or something?

Comment: You're missing a `,` before `"$businessName"`.

Answer (score 2):

As @Frank van Puffelen said I was just missing a comma before "$businessName".